# python - appending element to a list

Tags: python, list, index-error

I get error of list index out of range from the following code:

```
@register.filter(name='get_posts')
def get_posts(topic, limit):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(topic=topic)
    related_post = []
    for i in range(limit):
        related_post.append(posts[i]) [happens at this line]

    return related_post
```

Isn't it correct to add a new element to a list by using append?

Comment: Can you post the complete error message please?

Comment: What is the relation between `posts` and `limit`? Is it possible, for instance, for `posts` to have five elements, and for `limit` to be a thousand? Consider what might happen in that case.

Comment: @Kevin, limit is an integer I set to limit the amount of comments to be added to the new list

Comment: @Kevin, yes, that is the problem! Thank you!

Comment: `limit` must be less or equal to `len(posts)` so that you won't get an index error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `limit` may be larger than the number of filtered posts. You should take the minimum of the two:

```
for i in range(min(limit, len(posts))):
    related_post.append(posts[i])
```

But frankly, it could be much easier to implement this with slicing, and then you won't have to faff around with this `min` call

```
@register.filter(name='get_posts')
def get_posts(topic, limit):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(topic=topic)
    return posts[:limit]
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for any loop here, You can do it like,

```
@register.filter(name='get_posts')
def get_posts(topic, limit):
    related_post = Post.objects.filter(topic=topic)[:limit]
    return related_post
```